# How can I run additonal linux commands after compiling a latex file

Tags: latex, auctex, linux

I want to run the following commands when emacs compiles a latex file.

```bash
FILE="main.tex"  # currently opened buffer in the emacs
pdflatex -shell-escape -shell-escape -jobname=main_temp $FILE
mv main_temp.pdf main.pdf
open main.pdf
```

Goal: I am using following pdf editor (https://pdfexpert.com) to read my update tex file's generated pdf in dark mode.

By default when `pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode current_buffer.tex` is executed by emacs, during the compilation of the tex file,the pdf reader shows the following message with a white background for a few seconds, which hurts the eye when switching from black to white and then after compilation from white to black again.

[image]

So I just want to trick the pdf-reader to open the compiled pdf when emacs compiles a tex file to  a different name and move it to original pdf file when it completes its operation via:

```bash
mv paper_temp.pdf paper.pdf
open paper.pdf
```

minimal.el

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq user-init-file (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
(setq user-emacs-directory (file-name-directory user-init-file))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)

(require 'tex)
(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
             '("%(mode)"
               (lambda nil
                 (if TeX-interactive-mode ""
                   " -interaction=batchmode"))))

(setq TeX-command-extra-options " -shell-escape")

(defun my-run-latex ()
  "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((inhibit-message t)
         (TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
         (TeX-clean-confirm t)
         (TeX-save-query nil)
         (master (TeX-master-file))
         (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master))))
    (TeX-save-document master)
    (when (and (processp process)
               (eq (process-status process) 'run))
      (delete-process process))
    (TeX-command-master)))

(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'writegood-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)))
```

I'm using `my-run-latex()` function to compile my tex file.

Comment: Please clarify: You are using _my-run-latex()_ to compile your document and are looking for a modification of this function to "trick" the pdf-reader?

Comment: @StarBug yes sir exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret sauce is `TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions`.

This uses `browse-url-xdg-open` to open the file, so associate `pdfexpert` with `.pdf` files.

---

1. Create a dummy `xxx.org`
2. Export it to `xxx.tex` with `C-c C-e l p`
3. Create a `test.el` file with following contents

```lisp
;; FILE="paper.tex"  # currently opened buffer in the emacs
;; pdflatex -shell-escape -shell-escape -jobname=paper_temp $FILE;
;; mv paper_temp.pdf paper.pdf;
;; open paper.pdf;

(package-initialize)
(require 'package)

(require 'tex)
(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
             '("%(mode)"
               (lambda nil
                 (if TeX-interactive-mode ""
                   " -interaction=batchmode"))))

(defun my-run-latex ()
  "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((TeX-command-extra-options (format " -shell-escape -jobname=%s_temp" (TeX-master-file)))
         (inhibit-message t)
         (TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
         (TeX-clean-confirm t)
         (TeX-save-query nil)
         (master (TeX-master-file))
         (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master)))
         (temp-file (expand-file-name (format "%s_temp.pdf" (TeX-master-file)))))
    (TeX-save-document master)
    (when (and (processp process)
               (eq (process-status process) 'run))
      (delete-process process))
    (when (file-exists-p temp-file)
      (delete-file temp-file))
    (TeX-command-master)))

(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)))

(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
          (defun my-TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions (file-name)
            (message "compilation finished %s" file-name)
            (let ((temp-file (format "%s_temp.pdf" (file-name-sans-extension file-name))))
              (rename-file temp-file file-name t)
              (browse-url-xdg-open (browse-url-file-url file-name)))))
```

4. `emacs -Q`.  Note the use of `-Q`.
5. `C-x C-f ~/test.el`, do `M-x eval-buffer`
6. `C-x C-f ~/xxx.tex`
7. `M-x my-run-latex`
8. Profit!

---

Additional comment.

When I install the following watch for the dir where `~/xxx_temp.pdf` is located

```lisp
(require 'filenotify)

(defun watch-file-creation (filename)
  (message "Watching for creation of %s" filename)
  (file-notify-add-watch (file-name-directory filename)
             '(change)
             (lambda (event)
               ;; (message "event: %S" event)
               (pcase-let ((`(,descriptor ,action ,file ,file1) event))
                 (message "[%s] %s" action file)))))

(watch-file-creation (expand-file-name "~/xxx_temp.pdf"))
```

I get

```
Type ‘C-c C-l’ to display results of compilation.
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.log [6 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.aux [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.log [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.out [2 times]
[created] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.toc [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf [2 times]
LaTeX: problems after [0] pages
compilation finished /home/whitetrillium/xxx.pdf
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.aux [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf [2 times]
[changed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.log [2 times]
[deleted] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf
[renamed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf [2 times]
[created] /home/whitetrillium/xxx.pdf
```

which means that `pdf` file is getting created, and subsequently modified multiple times.

Note specifically the lines

```
compilation finished /home/whitetrillium/xxx.pdf
[deleted] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf
[renamed] /home/whitetrillium/xxx_temp.pdf [2 times]
[created] /home/whitetrillium/xxx.pdf
```

which summarizes what my `elisp` is doing, which is just what the original poster requested.

---

Comment: Instead of using  browser to open pdf files, I was opening the pdf file on native pdf editors.I am having a error as follows: error in process sentinel: `Searching for program: No such file or directory, xdg-open` can we use just `open` unix command to open the pdf file, instead of `browse-url-xdg-open`?

Comment: So, don't be confused by `browse` in the name.  It opens files with `file:///` url.  In my example `xxx.tex` is the file you are compiling and `xxx_temp.pdf` is the file that is passed as `jobname`.  The call back is called only on success.  So, I will be surprised the file output pdf file doesn't exist.  Instead of ` (browse-url-xdg-open (browse-url-file-url file-name)` you can use `(call-process "open" nil nil nil file-name)`.  What OS are you running? `xdg-open` is avaiable on Linux.  I have tested my change on my local machine with `emacs -Q`.  It is unlikely that there is an error ...

Comment: I am on macOS, ah `xdg-open` is not installed, seems like it runs inside xQuartz

Comment: You can use `open` instead.  Do an `M-: (call-process "open" nil 0 nil "somefile.pdf")` to see if it works for you.

Comment: `(call-process "open" nil 0 nil "somefile.pdf")` works! So should I do: `(call-process "open" nil 0 nil filename)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) as your latex command, you can run specific commands when the compile succeeds (or not). latexmk can be used as a wrapper for various latex compilers, for example `latexmk -pdflatex=xelatex -pdf %f` will use xelatex to generate a pdf.

try adding something like this to the `.latexmkrc` file

`$success_cmd = 'mv %A.pdf %A_temp.pdf && open %A_temp.pdf';`

Comment: Can't it be done using `pdflatex`?

Comment: sure.  something like `latexmk -r -pdflatex=pdflatex -pdf %f`

Comment: it gives following error: `Latexmk: RC file [-pdflatex=pdflatex] does not exist`

Comment: does `latexmk -pdflatex -pdf %f` work as expected?

Comment: I had to do `latexmk -f -pdflatex -pdf -shell-escape file.tex` this seems like works. I have tested in terminal but did not tested inside `emacs` tho

Answer (score 1):

`TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions` is a variable defined in `tex.el`.

Its value is (`my-TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions`)

**Hook being run after `TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt` *finished successfully*.** The functions in this hook are run with the `DVI/PDF` output file given as argument.  Using this hook can be useful for updating the viewer automatically after re-compilation of the document.

If you use an emacs-internal viewer such as `doc-view-mode` or `pdf-view-mode`, add `TeX-revert-document-buffer` to this hook.

This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.