# How can I open corresponding pdf of a tex file?

Tags: filenames

This question is the continuation of an earlier discussion here [How can I run additonal linux commands after compiling a latex file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72538/18414).

I have a opened tex file called let's say `filename.tex`, which also has its compiled pdf file called `filename.pdf`.

While the current buffer is `filename.tex`, I want open pdf-file using `(call-process "open" nil 0 nil "filename.pdf")` , please note that I am on `Mac`. I can get the file name using `buffer-file-name`  but I was not able to replace `.tex` into `.pdf` in order to open its pdf file.

How can I open corresponding pdf of a tex file, where its extension is replaced from `.tex` into `.pdf`?

Comment: [`file-name-with-extension`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html#index-file_002dname_002dwith_002dextension). You can get the answer by simply Google "emacs filename extension" and read the manual.

Comment: @TianshuWang I know but the given answer is much complicated than just using `file-name-with-extension`

Comment: `auctex` also has some functions like `TeX-view` to open the corresponding pdf. You should clarify what your needs are different.

Comment: You are right `TeX-view` does the job; I am sorry for not clarify my needs clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install this `emacs-lisp` code

```lisp
(defvar related-extns-alist
  '(("org" "pdf" "html" "odt")          ; When I open a `org' file
                                        ; with `C-u M-x browse-file',
                                        ; I really want to open any of
                                        ; the related `pdf', `html',
                                        ; or `odt' files
    ("tex" "pdf"))                      ; When I open a `tex' file
                                        ; with `C-u M-x browse-file',
                                        ; I really want to open any of
                                        ; `pdf' file
  )

(defun browse-file (file-name &optional related-file)
  "Open FILE-NAME using the default Desktop Application.
With a prefix argument, open a related file.  See
`related-extns-alist' for more information."
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-file-name "File name: "
                    nil                 ; dir
                    nil                 ; default-file-name
                    t                   ; mustmatch
                    (buffer-file-name))
    current-prefix-arg))
  (if-let* ((userp (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
            (browse-related-file current-prefix-arg)
            (related-extns
             (assoc-default
              (file-name-extension file-name) related-extns-alist))
            (other-readable-extns
             (seq-filter
              (lambda (extn)
                (let ((other-file (file-name-with-extension
                                   file-name extn)))
                  (when (file-readable-p other-file)
                    other-file)))
              related-extns))
            (actual-extension
             (cond
              ((= 1 (length other-readable-extns))
               (car other-readable-extns))
              (t (completing-read "Extn: " other-readable-extns)))))
      (browse-url-default-browser (browse-url-file-url
                                   (file-name-with-extension
                                    file-name actual-extension)))
    (browse-url-default-browser (browse-url-file-url file-name))
    ;; (find-file file-name)
    ))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-S-f") #'browse-file) ; This is C-x C-F
```

2. When you are in a `.tex` file, do `C-u C-x C-S-F filename.tex` or `C-u M-x browse-file RET filename.tex`.  It will open the `pdf` file in the app your choice.

If you visiting a `.org` file, you will be offered a choice of which of the related files `.html`, `.pdf`, or `.odt` you can use.

---

Since you are on a `Mac`, `browse-url-default-browser` will internally use `open`.  (I am on `Linux`, and it uses `xdg-open`)

Comment: `(concat (file-name-sans-extension file-name) "." actual-extension)` is equivalent to `(file-name-with-extension file-name actual-extension)` as @TianshuWang points out in a comment.

Comment: Ok. Recipe updated.  The question is not an API question, but a recipe question.  In fact it is the continuation of an earlier discussion here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72538/31220.  My comment answers  this specific user's needs.

Comment: I don't think you need the `(concat "." ...)`: just the extension is enough.

Comment: Ok. Made the requested  change.

Comment: @whitetrillium Do I need the provide file name (like `filename.tex`) as input or could it also be automatically taken from the opened buffer without entering it manually?

Comment: Try the command first ... If you re in `test.tex`, and if you do `C-u M-x browse-file` you will get a first prompt that says `test.tex` in minibuffer, just press RET--no need to alter it---and then it will ask for the extensions to use (if there are more than one).  In `tex` case there is only a `pdf` extension.  In `org` case there are three extensions `pdf`, `html`, `odt` etc.  Pick the extension you want to open.  If you are calling non-interactively, then you have to give the `.pdf` file as input.  (The function behaves differently based on interactive and non-interactive use)

Comment: You can also change the file-name at the minibuffer prompt  (just like as you do for `C-x C-f`)

Comment: @whitetrillium thank you I appreciated your well explained solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `M-x TeX-view` to open the .pdf file that corresponds to the .tex that you are viewing. It should be bound to `C-C C-v`.