# How can I prevent Ctrl+n to write into buffer?

Tags: key-bindings, control-characters

I am using `my-run-latex ()` function (explained here: [How can I run additonal linux commands after compiling a latex file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72538/18414)) after each save, which I do very often.

I bound it to: `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (λ () (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'my-run-latex)))`.

I observe than after enter `C-x C-s`, remove my finger from `s`, continue to press `Ctrl` and switch into press `n` (final comman will be `C-n`), once in a while instead of moving line below it shows `nnnnnn` in the buffer.

What could be the main reason for this? Does pdf compilation at the background cause this? Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Unclear: what does `ibuffer-mode-map` have to do with pressing `C-x C-s`  or `C-n` in `LaTeX-mode`?

Comment: sorry `ibuffer-mode-map` has nothing to do with this, removed from question

Comment: When this happens do `M-x view-lossage` and go to the bottom of buffer and see what `emacs` is doing (or what your fingers are doing without your brain's approval) ...

Comment: @whitetrillium I will `M-x view-lossage` and try to get some clue, but I am pretty sure my finger continues to press `Ctrl` during this happens , but emacs assumes I don't

Comment: Sounds like your keyboard or whatever is dropping the `Control` modifier key and thinking you're only holding down `n`.

Comment: @Drew Exactly that's the issue I am having. Can emacs prevent holding down characters to be written (like more than 5 in a very short duration) like hodling down only `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `@lawlist`'s comment I believe I find a lead to cause of the problem I was having.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51907085/2402577

> Garbage collection is generally a necessary evil, and can cause a noticeable pause; e.g., when holding down the arrow-key and moving left/right rapidly.

---

I had following lines in my config:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
          `(lambda ()
             (setq gc-cons-threshold 402653184
                   gc-cons-percentage 0.6)
             (garbage-collect)) t)

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook  ;; Profile emacs startup
          (lambda ()
            (message "*** Emacs loaded in %s with %d garbage collections."
                     (format "%.2f seconds"
                             (float-time
                              (time-subtract after-init-time before-init-time)))
                     gcs-done)))
```

I have messed up `gc-cons-threshold` or `gc-cons-percentage`. Removing those line seems like solved the pause and  drop of the `Control` modifier key.